# How to manage connection many to many for MySQL tables using RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have two MySQL tables 'experts' (id, name) and "languages" (id, title). On my web site I can provide name for experts and send to database (no problems).

```
$expert = R::dispense('experts');   
$expert->name = $data['name'];
R::store($expert);
```

Also, I have a table with over 100+ languages in database, which are shown in multiple drop-down menu on my web-site. 
How can I manage many to many connections between "experts" and "languages", so I can store couple/many languages for an expert in table experts_languages?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using that RedBeanPHP?

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t fully understand the question, but if you need to have the `experts` and`lang` connections, then I think the `many to many` method will work, here is an example from the `RedBeanPHP` website:

```
<?php
  list($vase, $lamp) = R::dispense('product', 2);

    $tag = R::dispense( 'tag' );
    $tag->name = 'Art Deco';

    //creates product_tag table!
    $vase->sharedTagList[] = $tag;
    $lamp->sharedTagList[] = $tag;
    R::storeAll( [$vase, $lamp] );
?>
```

OneToMany - https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/one_to_many

ManyToOne - https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/many_to_one

ManyToMany - https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/many_to_many

I personally used it, it may seem that there are too many lines, but everything is clear :)

```
<?php
//if u create new table
$exp = R::dispense('experts');
$exp->name = 'name';
R::store($exp);
$lang = R::dispense('language');
$lang->name = 'name';
R::store($lang);
//or if you need to interact with an existing post
$exp = R::load('experts',$eId);
$exp = R::load('language',$lId);
//

$el = R::dispense('experts_language'); //new table many to many
$el->experts = $exp;
$el->language = $lang;
R::store($el);

print_r($exp->ownExpertsLanguageList);
?>
```